# "~__vector_base() " having an excess run time in Wasm as well as an abort error. Cannot find the error

Tags: c++, vector, emscripten, webassembly

I've make a program to do a login procedure and had it working great, but when I went back and noticed a dynamically allocated variable (an object) not being deleted, I correct that and found my program to be extremely slow, taking about 3 seconds per each step, when it previously was instant.

I compiled in a debug mode, and the first thing I noticed was all the abort() errors being called.

[image]

I then ran a profile in chrome tools, giving this result.

[image]

This is the stack trace demangled,

```
_WoWAuthHandler::handleServerData(WoWPacket*)
   _WoWPacket::~WoWPacket()
      _Packet::~Packet()
         _Buffer::~Buffer()
            _Buffer::clear()
```

This is the code for ~Buffer() (Not my code)

```
Buffer::~Buffer() {
     clear();
}
```

Buffer::clear()

```
void Buffer::clear() noexcept {
    buffer.clear();
    readOffset = 0;
    writeOffset = 0;
}
```

buffer is a basic std::vector, but the std::vector.clear() isn't included in the stack trace and doesn't seem to be the issue.

I modified ~Buffer() to just be an empty function and ran another profile However, this only made it more confusing.

[image]

This is the demanged stack trace for that.

```
_WoWAuthHandler::handleServerData(WoWPacket*)
   _WoWPacket::~WoWPacket()
      _Packet::~Packet()
         _Buffer::~Buffer()
            _std::__2::vector<unsigned char, std::__2::allocator<unsigned char> >::~vector()
              _std::__2::__vector_base<unsigned char, std::__2::allocator<unsigned char> >::~__vector_base()
```

~Buffer() does not call anything.

I can control this massive delay from happening, but it involves removing the delete call on that first variable. Not being an option, as that variable is dynamically created.

```
void Socket::serverToHandler(int dataptr, int len) {
    uint8_t* dataraw = (uint8_t*)dataptr;
    std::vector<uint8_t>* dataParsed = Socket::parsePacket(dataraw, len);

    WoWPacket* dataReader = new WoWPacket(dataParsed);
    wowHandler->handleServerData(dataReader);
    delete dataReader;//If this is removed, the code runs without issue. However, it lags a huge amount with it. 

    delete dataraw;
    delete dataParsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be an error in emscripten itself.

If I compile with -g0 and -O0 it'll compile with the error above but
without changing any code, I can compile with -g0  and -O1 to have it compile fine.

If I compile with -g4 and -O1 it'll compile with the error above,
but if I compile with -g2 and -O1 it'll compile fine, and have enough debugging info  for my liking.

I'm using version 1.38.31

This solution works for me, just leaving an answer if anyone has this error in the future.

---

Update:
It came back, realized I was freeing the same pointer twice. 
DAMN YOU VAGUE C++ ERROR MESSAGES